# What is the correct way python memory management in case of exceptions?

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am writing my own Python module and need some advice. Let's consider an example function in a module:

```
PyObject* my_func(PyObject *self, PyObject* args)
{
    PyObject* returnObj;
    try
    {
       returnObj = my_create_output();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_Exception, ex.what());
        returnObj = NULL;
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

`my_create_output` function can raise different exceptions (also my own exceptions). `returnObj` is a big structure (for example, a list) and it may happen that `my_create_output` function will raise an exception when half of the output is already created. How should I delete the allocated objects in the `catch` block for such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_create_output` should handle the deallocation of everything it creates in the case of an exception, as a caller catching the exception has no way to access any of it.

Comment: Should I just use `Py_XDECREF` for allowing python interpreter to delete objects?

Comment: @SamvelHovsepyan: If your object is in a state where the ordinary destructor would clean it up properly, then `Py_XDECREF`ing it inside `my_create_output` would probably be the thing to do.